# "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'predict'". I am developing garbage detector model and this is the error

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import load_model
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import numpy as np

model = './ C:/Parth/cs11/converted_keras/saved_model.h5'


data = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.float32)

image = Image.open('C:/cs11/pic.jpg')

size = (224, 224)
image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

image_array = np.asarray(image)

normalized_image_array = (image_array.astype(np.float32) / 127.0) - 1

data[0] = normalized_image_array

prediction = model.predict(data)
print(prediction)
```

And the error i am receiving is

```
  File "cs11.py", line 22, in <module>
    prediction = model.predict('data')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

I am not able to understand why it is happening so even if data is an `np.ndarray.`
Could someone please tell me a way around this? Or an alternative method for it?

Comment: Your model variable only contains the path to the model. You need to do load it using the load_model function you've imported

Comment: without that i was still been able to load in the model.

Answer (score 1):

you specified the path to the model. Now you must load the model

```
model_path=r'./ C:/Parth/cs11/converted_keras/saved_model.h5'
model = keras.models.load_model(model_path)
```

now do predictions. You can check if the model loaded correctly with

```
print (model.summary())
```

This should print out the model summary

Comment: it then gives me the error of ```OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: ./ C:/Parth/cs11/converted_keras/saved_model.h5\{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}```

Comment: go to the directory where you think you saved the model and see if the files are there.

Comment: yes the file is there